# Facebook Login "The application domains must match the Facebook web game URL domains.."

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am creating an application to be able to log in with facebook on my page.

The problem is the following, I add without problem the following two domains:

- www.fumigadorweb.com.ar
- fumigadorweb.com.ar

The issue is that my site has two active domains, the other is *elfumigadorweb.com.ar*, the problem is that this domain is not allowing me to add it, it informs me of the following error:

[Image - error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGbiL.png)

> The application domains must match the Facebook web game URL domains
>   (https), mobile site URL, Unity binary URL, site URL, or secure URL of
>   the page tab. Fix the following domains:

I tried eliminating my other two records that it takes correctly, and adding only the one of the conflict, and neither did it.

Could you tell me what is the mistake I'm making? Do you need any other information?

From already thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

*elfumigadorweb.com.ar* is not a sub domain of your website (*http://www.fumigadorweb.com.ar*). your website. Valid sub domains should have *.fumigadorweb.com.ar pattern in your case. If it could be el.fumigadorweb.com.ar instead of  elfumigadorweb.com.ar then you could add it.

You have to create a new facebook app for *elfumigadorweb.com.ar*